# Given a psd matrix $Q$ and a kernel function $f(y_i, y_j)$, how do I find $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ that best approximates $Q$?

Tags: pca, kernel-trick, multidimensional-scaling

The question is basically the title. I have a matrix $Q$ that I know is positive semi-definite. I now want to find the $Y$ that approximates this matrix under some kernel function $f(y_i, y_j)$. I know that if the function $f$ is invertible then I can find the Gram matrix by applying $f^{-1}$ to each element of Q and then do multi-dimensional scaling... but this seems like a sloppy way to do it. Is there a cleaner method? Is there existing literature on this?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "under some kernel function"?

Comment: I am closing this question as I found the relevant response here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/345152/does-mercers-theorem-work-in-reverse

Comment: Thank you for finding the duplicate!